# show more than one pagination in same template file in drupal7

Tags: php, drupal-7, pagination

In my custom template tpl file, i am showing two sections (div content) of data, one from each function of my custom module.
The data also has pagination for it, displayed below.

Initially only one block of data will be displayed. Other block of data will be hidden on the page, unless the user clicks on a tab in the page.
   Now my question is, how can i show individual paginations for each of my blocks in the same page ?

If i click on a page link in block 1 and go to its page, the pagination links for another block must not be affected.
How to achieve this in Drupal 7?

```
// my custom module code below
// function one
func one() { 
$page = strtolower($page);
$query  = db_select('keyword', 'k');    
$query->groupBy('k.res');
$stories = $query->extend('PagerDefault')->limit(10)->execute();
return $stories;
}

// function two
func two() { 
$page = strtolower($page);
$query  = db_select('videos', 'v'); 
$query->groupBy('v.res');
$videos= $query->extend('PagerDefault')->limit(10)->execute();
return $videos;
}
```

> ```
> // in my custom template page
> // below is first section in same page
> $block_content = fun one(arg(1));
> $args = array( 'parameters' => array('pg' => 'one'));
> print (theme ('pager',$args));
> foreach($block_content as $content)
> {
>   // doing something to display
> }
> print (theme ('pager',$args));
>
> // below is second section in same page
> $block_content = fun two(arg(1));
> $args = array( 'parameters' => array('pg' => 'two'));
> print (theme ('pager',$args));
> foreach($block_content as $content)
> {
>   // doing something to display
> }
> print (theme ('pager',$args));
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`PagerDefault::element()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/PagerDefault%3a%3aelement/7) method to set a unique element ID for the pager:

```
// First one
$stories = $query->extend('PagerDefault')->element(0)->limit(10)->execute();

// Second one
$videos = $query->extend('PagerDefault')->element(1)->limit(10)->execute();
```

Then use the respective element ID in the theme call:

```
// First one
$args = array('element' => 0, ...);
print theme('pager', $args);

// Second one
$args = array('element' => 1, ...);
print theme('pager', $args);
```

Comment: This works well, however i had a small issue. I would like to pass unique parameters in the url for links under Stories and Videos. But when i am currently in a page of Stories, and navigate to a link under Videos, the url parameters are unchanged (Only parameters of stories pager show in url, but not parameters of Videos pager).

I am initializing the pagers like this:

**$args = array('parameters' => array('ps' => 'stories', 'pv'=>0), 'element' => 0); print theme('pager', $args);

$args = array('parameters' => array('pv' => 'videos', 'ps'=>0), 'element' => 1); print theme('pager', $args);**

Comment: I also faced an issue during a situation. When i navigate to a page under Videos, and then click on the last pagination link under Stories, the results show up blank. The url in that case is something like: **&page=10,5** (where **10** is the last page of **Stories** and **5** is the page i visited previously under **Videos**). However the results show up fine when i go to the url with page param as: **&page=10**.